# How to modify columns contents in a protein PDB file by keys and values stored in a text file using only bash tools

Tags: bash, bioinformatics

as written in the title of this post I am trying to replace values in the so-called B (temperature factor) and/or q (occupancy) columns of a PDB (Protein Data Bank) file that stores the 3D coordinates of every atom belonging to that protein. A simple two column csv file is the source file providing such values (in the second column) for a specific amino acid (sequential number in the first column)

A short example of source file (source.csv) limited to the first two amino acids (in the real dataset those are hundreds):

```
1, 11.25
2, 16.49
```

The corresponding block of the destination (dest.pdb) file is:

```
ATOM      1  N   MET A   1     105.382 119.360 102.631  1.00   0.00
ATOM      2 CA   MET A   1     105.155 118.751 103.942  1.00   0.00
ATOM      3 HA   MET A   1     104.645 119.496 104.551  1.00   0.00
ATOM      4 CB   MET A   1     104.212 117.542 103.804  1.00   0.00
ATOM      5HB1   MET A   1     104.120 117.057 104.775  1.00   0.00
ATOM      6HB2   MET A   1     104.631 116.826 103.095  1.00   0.00
ATOM      7 CG   MET A   1     102.801 117.937 103.353  1.00   0.00
ATOM      8HG1   MET A   1     102.862 118.327 102.336  1.00   0.00
ATOM      9HG2   MET A   1     102.436 118.736 103.999  1.00   0.00
ATOM     10 SD   MET A   1     101.579 116.590 103.371  1.00   0.00
ATOM     11 CE   MET A   1     101.404 116.275 105.156  1.00   0.00
ATOM     12HE1   MET A   1     100.603 115.555 105.325  1.00   0.00
ATOM     13HE2   MET A   1     102.327 115.865 105.565  1.00   0.00
ATOM     14HE3   MET A   1     101.158 117.201 105.676  1.00   0.00
ATOM     15  C   MET A   1     106.423 118.387 104.697  1.00   0.00
ATOM     16  O   MET A   1     107.511 118.334 104.134  1.00   0.00
ATOM     17  N   GLU A   2     106.296 118.095 105.999  1.00   0.00
ATOM     18  H   GLU A   2     105.398 118.148 106.454  1.00   0.00
ATOM     19 CA   GLU A   2     107.495 117.802 106.786  1.00   0.00
ATOM     20 HA   GLU A   2     108.068 118.718 106.664  1.00   0.00
ATOM     21 CB   GLU A   2     107.242 117.714 108.295  1.00   0.00
ATOM     22HB1   GLU A   2     106.839 116.732 108.520  1.00   0.00
ATOM     23HB2   GLU A   2     106.494 118.455 108.581  1.00   0.00
ATOM     24 CG   GLU A   2     108.519 117.970 109.128  1.00   0.00
ATOM     25HG1   GLU A   2     108.323 117.660 110.155  1.00   0.00
ATOM     26HG2   GLU A   2     109.328 117.336 108.762  1.00   0.00
ATOM     27 CD   GLU A   2     109.002 119.432 109.126  1.00   0.00
ATOM     28OE1   GLU A   2     109.449 119.916 108.058  1.00   0.00
ATOM     29OE2   GLU A   2     109.026 120.057 110.206  1.00   0.00
ATOM     30  C   GLU A   2     108.446 116.757 106.163  1.00   0.00
ATOM     31  O   GLU A   2     109.650 117.015 106.154  1.00   0.00
```

I need to get a result file (result.pdb):

```
ATOM      1  N   MET A   1     105.382 119.360 102.631  1.00  11.25
ATOM      2 CA   MET A   1     105.155 118.751 103.942  1.00  11.25
ATOM      3 HA   MET A   1     104.645 119.496 104.551  1.00  11.25
ATOM      4 CB   MET A   1     104.212 117.542 103.804  1.00  11.25
ATOM      5HB1   MET A   1     104.120 117.057 104.775  1.00  11.25
ATOM      6HB2   MET A   1     104.631 116.826 103.095  1.00  11.25
ATOM      7 CG   MET A   1     102.801 117.937 103.353  1.00  11.25
ATOM      8HG1   MET A   1     102.862 118.327 102.336  1.00  11.25
ATOM      9HG2   MET A   1     102.436 118.736 103.999  1.00  11.25
ATOM     10 SD   MET A   1     101.579 116.590 103.371  1.00  11.25
ATOM     11 CE   MET A   1     101.404 116.275 105.156  1.00  11.25
ATOM     12HE1   MET A   1     100.603 115.555 105.325  1.00  11.25
ATOM     13HE2   MET A   1     102.327 115.865 105.565  1.00  11.25
ATOM     14HE3   MET A   1     101.158 117.201 105.676  1.00  11.25
ATOM     15  C   MET A   1     106.423 118.387 104.697  1.00  11.25
ATOM     16  O   MET A   1     107.511 118.334 104.134  1.00  11.25
ATOM     17  N   GLU A   2     106.296 118.095 105.999  1.00  16.49
ATOM     18  H   GLU A   2     105.398 118.148 106.454  1.00  16.49
ATOM     19 CA   GLU A   2     107.495 117.802 106.786  1.00  16.49
ATOM     20 HA   GLU A   2     108.068 118.718 106.664  1.00  16.49
ATOM     21 CB   GLU A   2     107.242 117.714 108.295  1.00  16.49
ATOM     22HB1   GLU A   2     106.839 116.732 108.520  1.00  16.49
ATOM     23HB2   GLU A   2     106.494 118.455 108.581  1.00  16.49
ATOM     24 CG   GLU A   2     108.519 117.970 109.128  1.00  16.49
ATOM     25HG1   GLU A   2     108.323 117.660 110.155  1.00  16.49
ATOM     26HG2   GLU A   2     109.328 117.336 108.762  1.00  16.49
ATOM     27 CD   GLU A   2     109.002 119.432 109.126  1.00  16.49
ATOM     28OE1   GLU A   2     109.449 119.916 108.058  1.00  16.49
ATOM     29OE2   GLU A   2     109.026 120.057 110.206  1.00  16.49
ATOM     30  C   GLU A   2     108.446 116.757 106.163  1.00  16.49
ATOM     31  O   GLU A   2     109.650 117.015 106.154  1.00  16.49
```

in which the scores of an amino acid are applied to all its atoms in the last column.

It is worth to note that the pdb files have their own format that has to be maintained. Indeed, the dest.pdb has been produced by the line of code:

```
var=0.00
awk '{printf "%4s%7.0f%3s%6s%2s%4.0f%12.3f%8.3f%8.3f%6.2f%7.2f\n", 
$1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $var}' < a.pdb >> dest.pdb
```

In my unsuccessful attempts, I tried to match the integers in column1 of source.csv with the 6th field of dest.pdb. If so, replace the 11th field of pdb file with the values in the second column and in the same line of source.csv. Because this is a block of code of a much larger bash script I tried to do that using only bash tools. In particular, I tried extensively with awk, something like:

```
while read -r n score; do
awk -v x=$n -v y=$score '{if ($6 == $x) printf "%4s%7.0f%3s%6s%2s%4.0f%12.3f%8.3f%8.3f%6.2f%7.2f\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $y}' dest.pdb 
done < source.csv >> results.pdb
```

I got stuck at this stage and would appreciate any help to move on.
Thanks.

**UPDATE.**
I solved the above issues by the following strategy:
(1) Strip off the unnecessary hydrogen atoms that mess up because they have three digits atomnames. I did with a dedicate small program called Reduce [http://kinemage.biochem.duke.edu/software/reduce.php][1]
(2) remove the header lines inserted by Reduce:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^ATOM/' A_temp.pdb >> A.pdb
```

(3)use read as parser in bash:

```
while  read -r atom anum aname resname chain resnum x y z q b ; do
       while  read -r n evol ; do
       if [[ ${resnum} == ${n} ]]
       then
       echo "$atom $anum $aname $resname $chain $resnum $x $y $z $q $evol" >> out.pdb
      fi
      done < source.tsv
     done < A.pdb
```

(4) Format the A.pdf file with awk:

```
awk '{printf "%4s%7.0f%5s%4s%2s%4.0f%12.3f%8.3f%8.3f%6.2f%6.2f\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11}' < out.pdb >> Aform.pdb

echo 'TER' >> Aform.pdb
```

Comment: Is the file separated by tabs? How do you handle `29OE2` and `30  C`?

Comment: Hi Kamil, the file is formatted in such a way 29 and OE2 belong to two adjacent fields. The same for 30 and C.

Comment: Is the file separated by tabs? or by spaces? The most difficutly is just in that field. Is it always going to be exactly 5 characters in length? Is it separated by a t least one leading space and one trailing space? Except for this field, you can simply use `join` with `cut`. Or if the file is separated by tabs.

Comment: @KamilCuk, PDB format is neither separated by tabs nor spaces. The columns define the contents: from column 1 to 6, the record name, 7 to 11, serial... http://www.wwpdb.org/documentation/file-format-content/format33/sect9.html#ATOM

Comment: Kamil, I posted how I managed to tackle my problem. I thank you and David for your contribution. At this point I suggest you to reconsider the bash  
command     read     as a very useful parser of data files as demonstrated in my piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

Bash is not a fully grown perfect parsing tool. Bash is good with delimetered files, and is not very good with it either. I would suggest to write a simple C++ or python program for your goal, it would work way simpler, faster and secure.

For bash, we need to first transform the file into something parsable. I choose to use tab to separate fields. Fields in [the format](http://www.wwpdb.org/documentation/file-format-content/format33/sect9.html#ATOM) you posted have constant lenght - so I will insert tabs at specified positions in the file. The "specified positions" are the field endings/beginnings in the rows in to file. I insert tabs from the end, so that the character numbering doesn't get mixed up.

```
sed '
    s/./\t&/79;
    s/./\t&/77;
    s/./\t&/61;
    s/./\t&/55;
    s/./\t&/47;
    s/./\t&/39;
    s/./\t&/31;
    s/./\t&/27;
    s/./\t&/23;
    s/./\t&/22;
    s/./\t&/18;
    s/./\t&/17;
    s/./\t&/13;
    s/./\t&/7;
'
```

After that we can use all the standard unix utilities to parse the files. I used simply join with a custom format string to join the files and print what I want. Then I can just remove the separator to restore the format.

```
# join on field 7 - resSeq
join -17 -21 -t$'\t' \
    -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,1.10,1.11,1.12,2.2 \
    -- <(
        # convert input file to tab separated file
        <dest.pdb \
        sed '
            s/./\t&/79;
            s/./\t&/77;
            s/./\t&/61;
            s/./\t&/55;
            s/./\t&/47;
            s/./\t&/39;
            s/./\t&/31;
            s/./\t&/27;
            s/./\t&/23;
            s/./\t&/22;
            s/./\t&/18;
            s/./\t&/17;
            s/./\t&/13;
            s/./\t&/7;
        ' |
        # sort it for join
        sort -t$'\t' -k7
    ) <(
        # convert input file for tab separated file
        <source.csv \
        tr ',' '\t' |
        # well squeese spaces, we format below
        tr -d ' ' |
        # the resSeq is 7 field length
        # you need to explicitly add spaces in front of the number
        # decide on which format do you use
        xargs -n2 printf "% 4d\t%7.2f\n" |
        # sort for join
        sort -t$'\t' -k1
) |
# I noticed the file was sorted using the `serial` field
sort -t$'\t' -n -k2 |
# and finally - remove bash separator
tr -d '\t'
```

I assumed the file is sorted using the second column, so I sorted it on output. I also don't know how to interpret the last field length `Real(6.2)` - I used printf `"%7.2"` modifier to print it.

Live version available at [tutorialspoint](http://tpcg.io/9O1pBW)

Comment: Hi Kamil, sorry for the late reply. I run your code and went as expected with the exception that it put a comma instead of a dot inside the values in the last column. When I run it on real data the same above problem occurs and I get an error  message:    join: /dev/fd/63:11: is not sorted: ATOM     132   CG2   VAL  A  10       117.921  114.080  103.705   1.00   5.32
join: /dev/fd/62:2: is not sorted:   10    0,01                                                             Also the output pdb file start with aminoacid 8 instead of 1.

Comment: `comma instead of a dot` Try setting `export LC_ALL=C` or similar before all the code, or experimenting with LC_COLLATE, otherwise you get regional dependent results (same with sorting)

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you need using an *associative array* to hold the csv values and then looping over the lines in `dest.pdb` calling `sed` to make the replacement based on the 26th character in the line as the index for the array used in the `sed` substitution.

(**note:** this violates the efficiency rule of calling `sed` (or any other utility) within the body of your loop, but it is necessary in some cases. If you have a million lines to convert -- go get a cup of coffee)

The reason this is a challenge and something not easily done in a single `awk` call is your second field contains *whitespace*, e.g.

```
...    1  N   ...
```

(while you can include conditionals based on `NF`, and that is what you will ultimately want to do, the following was what first came to mind)

The implementation in a short script would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A arr  ## declare & fill associative array from source.csv
while IFS=$' ,\t\n' read n v; do 
    arr[$n]=$v
done <source.csv

## read/covert last value in line using 26th char as index for array
#  and simple sed substitution to replace. 
#  (use braced group to redirect output)
{
while IFS= read -r line; do 
    sed "s/0[.]00$/${arr[${line:25:1}]}/" <<< "$line"
done <dest.pdb
} > results.pdb
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your data files as you have presented above, simply running the script in the directory containing both `source.csv` and `dest.pdb` would result in `results.pdb` as follows:

```
$ cat results.pdb
ATOM      1  N   MET A   1     105.382 119.360 102.631  1.00   11.25
ATOM      2 CA   MET A   1     105.155 118.751 103.942  1.00   11.25
ATOM      3 HA   MET A   1     104.645 119.496 104.551  1.00   11.25
ATOM      4 CB   MET A   1     104.212 117.542 103.804  1.00   11.25
ATOM      5HB1   MET A   1     104.120 117.057 104.775  1.00   11.25
ATOM      6HB2   MET A   1     104.631 116.826 103.095  1.00   11.25
ATOM      7 CG   MET A   1     102.801 117.937 103.353  1.00   11.25
ATOM      8HG1   MET A   1     102.862 118.327 102.336  1.00   11.25
ATOM      9HG2   MET A   1     102.436 118.736 103.999  1.00   11.25
ATOM     10 SD   MET A   1     101.579 116.590 103.371  1.00   11.25
ATOM     11 CE   MET A   1     101.404 116.275 105.156  1.00   11.25
ATOM     12HE1   MET A   1     100.603 115.555 105.325  1.00   11.25
ATOM     13HE2   MET A   1     102.327 115.865 105.565  1.00   11.25
ATOM     14HE3   MET A   1     101.158 117.201 105.676  1.00   11.25
ATOM     15  C   MET A   1     106.423 118.387 104.697  1.00   11.25
ATOM     16  O   MET A   1     107.511 118.334 104.134  1.00   11.25
ATOM     17  N   GLU A   2     106.296 118.095 105.999  1.00   16.49
ATOM     18  H   GLU A   2     105.398 118.148 106.454  1.00   16.49
ATOM     19 CA   GLU A   2     107.495 117.802 106.786  1.00   16.49
ATOM     20 HA   GLU A   2     108.068 118.718 106.664  1.00   16.49
ATOM     21 CB   GLU A   2     107.242 117.714 108.295  1.00   16.49
ATOM     22HB1   GLU A   2     106.839 116.732 108.520  1.00   16.49
ATOM     23HB2   GLU A   2     106.494 118.455 108.581  1.00   16.49
ATOM     24 CG   GLU A   2     108.519 117.970 109.128  1.00   16.49
ATOM     25HG1   GLU A   2     108.323 117.660 110.155  1.00   16.49
ATOM     26HG2   GLU A   2     109.328 117.336 108.762  1.00   16.49
ATOM     27 CD   GLU A   2     109.002 119.432 109.126  1.00   16.49
ATOM     28OE1   GLU A   2     109.449 119.916 108.058  1.00   16.49
ATOM     29OE2   GLU A   2     109.026 120.057 110.206  1.00   16.49
ATOM     30  C   GLU A   2     108.446 116.757 106.163  1.00   16.49
ATOM     31  O   GLU A   2     109.650 117.015 106.154  1.00   16.49
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions. I'll go look at additional logic with `awk` and let you know if I come up with something there.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your answer. I will definitively try ASAP your script (today I cannot). Reading your explanation it is now clear to me that the difficulty of this task was beyond my coding skills. Regards.

Comment: Hi David, sorry for the late reply. In my hands your script did not work because it correctly apply substitution only for the first aminoacid while the second the filed is just empty. Whet I run it with real data I get the error message:                            
    ./david.sh: line 13: arr: bad array subscript

Comment: So you get output different that what is shown above? You are using bash right? Using `#!/bin/bash` at the top and not `#!/bin/sh` right? Let me know, because the script works 100% correct when using bash, but will not work as written using POSIX shell, because POSIX shell does not have the `"<<<"` (*herestring*) and you would simply need to pipe to `sed` instead of using a *herestring*. If not using bash, make it `echo "$line" | sed "s/0[.]00$/${arr[${line:25:1}]}/"`. POSIX doesn't have the array indexes either, so we will need an `expr` command substitution for that.

Comment: For POSIX, you would need `$(expr substr "$line" 26 1)` instead of `${line:25:1}` for the index for `arr`. You tagged the question `bash`, so make sure you are using `bash` as the command interpreter by having `#!/bin/bash` at the top of your script. The bash implementation will be a bit faster than a POSIX implementation. But if you really don't have `bash` and are using POSIX shell, then just make the two changes needed, (1) pipe `"$line"` to `sed` and (2) use the `expr substr ...` expression to get the `1, 2` from each line.

Comment: I use bash in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.     #!/usr/bin/env bash    is at the top of the script

Comment: Shouldn't matter, I've always used `#!/bin/bash` (should do the same thing) give it a try). There is no reason you would have any difference (unless your input file is different) I copied/pasted from your question, so all my fields are space delimited, if yours are `tab` delimited, that could change the number in `${line:25:1}` Do this, `line="ATOM      1  N   MET A   1     105.382 119.360 102.631  1.00   11.25"; for ((i = 0; i < ${#line}; i++) printf "line[%2d] : %c\n" $i ${line[i]}; done` and see what index your `1, 2` column is. That's the only thing it could be if you have bash.

Comment: Also, `hexdump -Cv inputfile` and confirm if it contains `tab` characters. Hex `0x09` (which you will see as just `09` is the `horizontal tab` character. The whitespace I in the `dest.pdb` is all space characters (`0x20`).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the data correctly you want,
     MET = 11.25 and GLU = 16.49

I would just issue two sed commands from the command line. My sed's is rusty, but approximately (i.e. I've not tested it), 
If you are going from 0.00 -> 11.25 and 0.00 -> 16.49 then,

```
sed 's/^(.+MET.+)0\.00/\1 11\.25/' myfile.pdb > outfile
sed 's/^(.+GLU.+)0\.00/\1 16\.49/' myfile.pdb >> outfile
```

Just flip the numbers between from the first set of brackets '/first/' to the second set of brackets '/first/second/' if you want the operation reversing, i.e. from 11.25 -> 0.00 etc...

**sed users would tighten this (and likely debug it!), by constructing it as a single script. I'll only do this under duress.**

The solutions proposed here use regex and in my opinion it is better implemented in other languages, but sed is an easy way to learn regex because it is just pure regex and doesn't require any other programming knowledge.